# subplot layout - Noise waveform with modifiable offset

Tags: framed, subplot

I'm trying to build a graph with the layout similar to the figure below:

[image]

I'm using the 'minipage' environment and my code is shown below.

```
\section{Figures}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering  
    \caption{teste.}
    \label{c00fig00}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.55]{c01fig01a.eps}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.55]{c01fig01c.eps}
    \end{minipage}%
    \\
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.55]{c01fig01b.eps}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
```

result is this:

[image]

But I am not able to align the graph on the right to make it bigger, and include the arrows as shown in the previous figure. Could someone give some suggestion?

thanks in advance

**#---EDITED QUESTION---#**

I made a small change in my code

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
        \flushleft
        \includegraphics[scale=0.55]{c01fig01a.eps}
        \\
        \includegraphics[scale=0.55]{c01fig01b.eps}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
        \flushright
        \includegraphics[scale=0.55]{c01fig01c.eps}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
```

and got the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have your plots but which Ti*k*Z it is straightforward to arrange them as you want. You need to replace `example-image-a` and so on by the names of your plots.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\section{Figures}
\begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=left]
   \node(fig1){\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
   \node[below=1cm of fig1](fig2){\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-b}};
  \end{scope} 
  \node[right=1cm of left,circle,draw,minimum size=3em,align=center,thick,
  path picture={\draw (path picture bounding box.south west)
  -- (path picture bounding box.north east) 
  (path picture bounding box.south east)
  -- (path picture bounding box.north west);},font=\large] (pp) {+\\[0.5ex] +};
  \node[right=1cm of pp] (fig3)
   {\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-duck}};
  \draw[very thick,-latex] (fig1) -| (pp);
  \draw[very thick,-latex] (fig2) -| (pp);
  \draw[very thick,-latex] (pp) -- (fig3);
 \end{tikzpicture}    
 \caption{Teste.}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: @NEricson You're welcome!